# Scrollbar not expanded when a div is fading in (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

hello to all world builders :)
I am using a jquery function to show and hide several div with fadeIn and fadeOut function.
They are invisible as default and when I change option of a select they are fading in and out.
The problem is when that divs are fading in scrollbar not expanded and footer disappears. (sorry for my bad English). 
Here is my code:

```
$('#act_type').change(function(){
           var divID = $(this).children('option:selected').attr('value');
           if(divID == '1'){
                $('#haqiqi').fadeOut(1000);
                $('#haqiqi2').fadeOut(500);
                $('#hoquqi').fadeIn(500);
                $('#hoquqi2').fadeIn(500);
                $('#hoquqi3').fadeIn(500);
           }else if(divID == '2'){
                $('#hoquqi').fadeOut(1000);
                $('#hoquqi2').fadeOut(1000);
                $('#hoquqi3').fadeOut(1000);
                $('#haqiqi').fadeIn(500);
                $('#haqiqi2').fadeIn(500);
           }else if(divID == '3'){
                $('#hoquqi').fadeIn(500);
                $('#hoquqi2').fadeIn(500);
                $('#hoquqi3').fadeIn(500);
                $('#haqiqi').fadeIn(500);
                $('#haqiqi2').fadeIn(500);
           }else{
                $('#hoquqi').fadeOut(1000);
                $('#hoquqi2').fadeOut(1000);
                $('#hoquqi3').fadeOut(1000);
                $('#haqiqi').fadeOut(1000);
                $('#haqiqi2').fadeOut(1000);
           }
        });

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" id="zero-m">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Choosing options:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <select name="act_type" id="act_type" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
                    <option value="1">Huquqi</option>
                    <option value="2">Haqiqi</option>
                    <option value="3">both</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
    <div class="header bg-orange">
        <h5>
           Card Header Text Here <small></small>
        </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <div id="haqiqi">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6" id="zero-m">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>something here:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="haqiqi2">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6" id="zero-m">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>something here:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
    <div class="header bg-orange">
        <h5>
           Card Header Text Here <small></small>
        </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="body">

        <div id="hoquqi">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6" id="zero-m">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>something here:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="hoquqi2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6" id="zero-m">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>something here:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="hoquqi3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6" id="zero-m">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>something here:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have placed them in two separated cards. If I place them in one card there will be no problem but I can't do that because I need cards header and styles.

How can I fix this?

Comment: add your respective HTML that you are using with this script

Comment: I have added it.